# Rails collection_select syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having issues with the following code:

```
  = f.collection_select :ch_professional, @ch_professionals
```

I'm trying to set the `ch_professional` field with a select. `@ch_professionals` is an array of strings.

I'm getting the following error:

> ActionView::Template::Error ({} is not a symbol)

I've looked for documentation on `collection_select`, and I haven't been able to find the correct syntax.

Comment: What issues exactly?

Comment: I think my syntax is wrong. I'm getting the following error:

ActionView::Template::Error ({} is not a symbol):

Answer (score 1):

Signature for `collection_select` is

> collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})

It expects the `value_method` and `text_method` to be symbols with method names that will be called to get corresponding values from each array element.

Error about `{}` is because of the way rails handles options hashes, it happened that default hash value of `{}` ended up in `value_method`.

So try something like:

```
= f.collection_select :ch_professional, @ch_professionals, :to_s, :to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `select` form helper if you just have an array of strings and do not need to have different values for the value and text of the options  e.g.

```
= f.select :ch_professional, @ch_professionals
```